# Elasticsearch bool query. Which clause has been used?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple query bool with 3 clauses :

```
query: {
    bool: {        
        should: [
            {
                query_string: {
                    default_field : 'name',
                    query: req.query.q                      
                }       
            }, 
            {
                prefix: { 
                    name: req.query.q 
                }
            },
            {
                match: { city: req.query.q }
            }
        ],
        minimum_should_match : 1
    }               
}
```

I would like to know which clause(s) has matched to return results.
For example if clause `match: { city: req.query.q }` has been used, I would like to be able to get that information in hits informations.

Comment: for debugging  [explain](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html#search-request-explain) would give this information else you could probably do a work around by enabling [highlighting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#search-request-highlighting) on the fields used in the query